# What is the use of @RequestMapping("VIEW") annotation in Spring Portlet MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, portlet

In my Spring portlet controller class, I have this at the class level:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public class myContoller extends AbstractController
```

Now the `@RequestMapping` is supposed to map a request url to an action handler(controller). 
But what is the use of saying `@RequestMapping("VIEW").`

In the `portlet.xml`, I have `<portlet-mode>VIEW</portlet-mode>` defined for this particular portlet controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Portlets can support different modes (default being `VIEW`, `EDIT` and `HELP` if I remember correctly).

`<portlet-mode>VIEW</portlet-mode>` in `portlet.xml` says that the portlet supports `VIEW` mode.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("VIEW") 
public class myContoller extends AbstractController
```

simply limits requests handled by `@RequestMapping` annotated methods of this controller to those sent in `VIEW` mode.